# Horizontal center desktop navbar menu in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, navbar

I am developing a navbar menu that I want to be perfectly horizontally centered. I am using React and Tailwind.

```
      <div className="px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"> {/* mx-auto max-w-7xl */}
        <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
          <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
            {/* Mobile menu button*/}
            <Disclosure.Button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
              <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
              {open ? (
                <XMarkIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              ) : (
                <Bars3Icon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
              )}
            </Disclosure.Button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
            <div className="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block">
              <div className="flex space-x-4">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <a
                    key={item.name}
                    href={item.href}
                    className={'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium'}
                    aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How do I perfectly center the navbar? I have tried `class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">` but it didn't have any impact. Here is the rest of the code

```
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '#Home' },
  { name: 'Podcast', href: '#Podcast' },
  { name: 'Tyler', href: '#Me' },
  { name: 'Code', href: '#Code' },
  { name: 'About', href: '#About' },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}
```

Comment: Try to make a minimal reproducible example at [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/). Also `justify-center` and `items-center` center items that are inside the navbar *not* the navbar itself.